# Scrape through website and iterate over seach results to get specific data

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to work on a project to scrape www.boattrader.com to push 800 listings with the Make, Price, and Phone Number of each boat to a CSV file.

I'm looking for guidance on the best way to scrape the links to each boat listing from the search results and then parse through each individual page to grab the Make, Price and Phone number.

Any guidance would be much appreciated it!

Thanks again!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests


def extract_from_search(search_results):
    # make this into a function
    r = requests.get(search_results)
    ad_page_html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ad_page_html, 'html.parser')

    possible_links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'btn btn-orange'})

    for link in possible_links:
        if link.has_attr('href'): 
            boat_links = link.attrs['href']

    return boat_links

search_results = 'http://www.boattrader.com/search-results/NewOrUsed-any/Type-all/Zip-90007/Radius-2000/Sort-Length:DESC/Page-1,50'
boat_links = extract_from_search(search_results)
print boat_links #why does this only print one link? What would be the best way to iterate over the search results, so I can put those links into the boat_listing variable to grab the information I'm looking for?

def extract_from_listing(boat_listing):
    r = requests.get(boat_listing)
    ad_page_html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ad_page_html, 'html.parser')

    table_heads = soup.find_all('th')

    for th in table_heads:
        if th.text =="Make": 
            make = th.find_next_sibling("td").text 

    price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'bd-price'})

    formatted_price = price.string.strip()

    contact_info = soup.find('div', {'class': 'phone'})
    reversed_phone = contact_info.string[::-1]

    temp_phone = reversed_phone.replace(')', '}')
    temp_phone2 = temp_phone.replace('(', ')')
    correct_phone = temp_phone2.replace("}", "(")

    return make, formatted_price, correct_phone

boat_listing = 'http://www.boattrader.com/listing/2009-Briggs-BR9134-Sportfish-102290211'
make, price, phone = extract_from_listing(boat_listing)
print make
print price
print phone
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning the last link, you need to append:

```
def extract_from_search(search_results):
    # make this into a function
    r = requests.get(search_results)
    ad_page_html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ad_page_html, 'html.parser')

    possible_links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'btn btn-orange'})
    boat_links = [] # create list to append all inks to 
    for link in possible_links:
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            boat_links.append(link.attrs['href']) # append each link
    return boat_links
```

Or use a list comp:

```
def extract_from_search(search_results):
    # make this into a function
    r = requests.get(search_results)
    ad_page_html = r.content # use content to let requests handle the decoding
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ad_page_html, 'html.parser')
    possible_links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'btn btn-orange'})
    return [link.attrs['href'] for link in possible_links if link.has_attr('href')]
```